# Navigation menu in Salesforce1 for communities disappeared with Summer 14?

Tags: community, salesforce1-app

I realised that the Navigation menu has disappeared when displaying a visualforce page in Salesforce1 for communities

I have created a very simple page with no logic at all to verify this which is the following

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    Hi {!$User.FirstName}
</apex:page>
```

When I login as a normal user the page and the navigation menu are rendered as expected.

When I login as a community user (Chrome using /one/one.app and Safari in iOS) the navigation menu is replaced with the back button !

It was working fine until the org was upgraded to Summer 14.

Has anybody else experienced something similar ? Is this normal ?

Comment: Did this get fixed, or is there a workaround? I am having this issue in Customer Community when navigating in the app through custom VF pages, the back button replaces the menu.

Answer (score 0):

This has been classified as a bug from Salesforce. I don't have a planned fix date yet, but hopefully it's gonna be fixed soon.